# git commit integrity

Tags: git, dvcs

I tried to search for what is git commit consists of and what parts takes part in commit's sha hash. But probably I was asking wrong words I found nothing.

I wonder what commit consists of. I read community book a bit and there is following image:

[image]

However I think that commit has more fields than shown in the image.

Now the main question: what fields are taking part in commit sha hash? I am asking that cause I got two commits in different repositories with the same sha hash, but with different parent commits. Before that I thought that two commits may have the same sha hash if they are the same and has the same parent commit. So I am a bit confused.

I have two local repositories (git1, git2)  one is a clone of other.

**git1**

```
commit 4f438f9579939312689eb67e5fb7957d87cfa036 <-- this commit
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 25 00:00:31 2012 +0300

    stuff after change

commit e91e833158bb44f54f418cc5c3e1832452051428
Merge: dc69dc2 0b5912b
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:09:18 2012 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of e:/temp/git2

    Conflicts:
        file.file

commit 0b5912bd1a1cb9b78410fe5c0dc67845ca1deec5
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:06:46 2012 +0300

    c8

commit dc69dc25a1e0c9067cbca19fe6a1d078a19138a0
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:06:29 2012 +0300

    c7

commit f6d88da1ecc3106f6debe1eac80d4b02705bcecf
Merge: d1a3c38 6134e66
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:05:05 2012 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of e:/temp/git1

    Conflicts:
        file.file

commit d1a3c389416ff88e195e93def9a956fad1e63819
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:03:47 2012 +0300
```

**git2**

```
commit e1ee3b2756d4d8440ae3661df3fb3ec9af7cd55a
Merge: 4296e1b 4f438f9
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 25 00:01:30 2012 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of e:/temp/git1

    Conflicts:
        file.file

commit 4f438f9579939312689eb67e5fb7957d87cfa036 <-- this commit
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 25 00:00:31 2012 +0300

    stuff after change

commit 4296e1bd046c4008166cfc516ef5ee2ce98a27d1
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jun 24 23:57:14 2012 +0300

    more stuff

commit e91e833158bb44f54f418cc5c3e1832452051428
Merge: dc69dc2 0b5912b
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:09:18 2012 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of e:/temp/git2

    Conflicts:
        file.file

commit 0b5912bd1a1cb9b78410fe5c0dc67845ca1deec5
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:06:46 2012 +0300

    c8

commit dc69dc25a1e0c9067cbca19fe6a1d078a19138a0
Author: Michael Nesterenko <misha@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 7 02:06:29 2012 +0300
```

That commits has different parents but the same sha hashes.

Comment: What makes you think that the commit has different parents in each repository? Please show the result of `git cat-file commit 4f438f9579939312689eb67e5fb7957d87cfa036 ` in each repository. Also, what log command did you run to generate the output that you've posted?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, log outputs made me think so. But for some reason now `git log` on both repositories shows the same parent commit for `4f438f9579939312689eb67e5fb7957d87cfa036`. Weird! Before there was `e91e833158bb44f54f418cc5c3e1832452051428` on `git1` and `4296e1bd046c4008166cfc516ef5ee2ce98a27d1` on `git2`.

Comment: What options did you supply to log? If you don't do something like `--graph` you can't see the actual parent relationships and will see all the commits that you ask for in a reasonably logical order but you cannot be sure that a commit shown before another commit is a direct descendant or not.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, no options, just `git log`

Comment: In your second log output, note that 4296e1b... is one of two merges merged into e1ee3b2... along with 4f438f9.... Both 4296e1b... and 4f438f9... are parents of e1ee3b2... so must appear after e1ee3b2... in the log output but just because one is printed before the other in the log doesn't mean the two are related by a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is vanishingly improbable that two different commits in clones of the same repository have the same id but different commits. The list of parents *is* part of the data for a commit that is hashed. To see the data that is hashed you can run:

```
git cat-file commit <id-of-commit>
```

The actual data that is hashed is a header consisting of: `<type> <size>\0` followed by the data for the commit. E.g. for a commit in my git clone:

```
$ printf 'commit %d\0' $(git cat-file commit 5498c5f05283cd248fd5e4f48cb8902e9ca6ce28 | wc -c) >tmp.dat
$ hexdump -C tmp.dat
00000000  63 6f 6d 6d 69 74 20 33  30 34 00                 |commit 304.|
0000000b
$ git cat-file commit 5498c5f05283cd248fd5e4f48cb8902e9ca6ce28 >>tmp.dat
$ sha1sum tmp.dat
5498c5f05283cd248fd5e4f48cb8902e9ca6ce28  tmp.dat
```

Note the sha1sum matches the commit id, and the parent is part of the commit object:

```
$ git cat-file commit 5498c5f05283cd248fd5e4f48cb8902e9ca6ce28 | grep parent
parent 3ba46634202968045e05e4d7f969d97c61efa53d
```

`git log` outputs a flat list of commits but commits in git form a directed acyclic graph. As the log is a flattened list of commits it will only directly reflect the commit to parent relationship in the trivial case of a simple linear history. If you have any merges (or are logging multiple branches) you will not be able to infer parentage relationships directly from the output of `git log` .

To show the actual links  from commit to parents you would need to use something like `git log --graph` (with which  I normally recommend `--oneline`) or a graphical visualization tool such as `gitk`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you tell some reason that could lead `git log` to arrange commits in such order (with wrong parent commit before)? I always thought that commit below is a parent (or at least one of parents) for commit upper in that list.

Comment: I could repeat that behaviour. There are no problems with parent commits they are as they are supposed to be. That seems to be a way how `git log` shows commits. This happens after hard reset on one of repositories and subsequent pull on the second.

Comment: @mishanesterenko: A log is a list of commits. Just because one commit appears after another doesn't necessarily mean that it is a parent of the preceding commit. `git log` isn't showing the "wrong parent" because it is not showing parent relationship. You are inferring that meaning when it is not there.

Comment: I'd like to add that the 40-hex-char digest has (2^4)^40 == 2^160 ~= 1.5*10^48 possible states. This makes it very unlikely that you will have any collisions.